# ExpressJs Sessions Not Lasting After the Window Closes

Tags: express, session

In Expressjs, i have some code to use cookie session, which is a middleware that is like express-session, but it keeps the session even after the server restarts. I was looking at other questions, but they all said that you should add a maxAge attr to the cookie. I did this, and the session still expires after the browser closes. Here:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('cookie-session');

app.use(session({
  name: 'session',
  secret: `secret`,
  httpOnly: true,
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999*9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999*999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999),
  maxAge: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999*9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999*999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
  signed: true
}));
```

This is was shown in other questions, (besides the expires and maxAge being very long). So, what is my problem? Again, i would like to make the session last even after the window closes, right now it lasts after the tab closes but not the entire window. This only needs to work in Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: The resulting date for your `expires` key is "Invalid Date" and `maxAge` is `Infinity` - is this on purpose?

Comment: how do i make it not infinity and not an invalid date

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
app.use(session({
      secret: "session",
      resave: true,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      key: 'express.sid'
}));
```

Otherwise, I would save the cookie to database, and always compare user's cookie with cookies in db.

P.S.

**Note** If both expires and maxAge are set in the options, then the last one defined in the object is what is used.

*source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session*